# Which is the highest version of Solr that is compatible with the "Apache Solr Search" module?

Tags: 7, search

I have a setup of Drupal 7 with the [Apache Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module. I am planning to upgrade the solr server's current installed version(3.6) to a higher version.

The latest version of [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) available in their site is 8.5.1.

Which is the highest version of Solr that is compatible with the module?

Answer (score 0):

Given there is an issue in the project issue queue ([Solr 7 integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr/issues/2972851)) about allowing to use the module with Solr 7, the module is at the moment only compatible with Solr 5 and eventually Solr 6.

Notice that the [README.txt](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/apachesolr/-/blob/7.x-1.x/README.txt) file has not been updated since 6 years ago and that the [solr-conf](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/apachesolr/-/tree/7.x-1.x/solr-conf) directory contains configuration files for Solr 1.4, 3.x, 4.x, and 5.x. This means the module has been tested with Solr 5.x, at least the 5.x version that was available 4 years ago.